# .net Applications hang for several seconds

Tags: windows-update, .net-framework, winforms

In a company I have installed 3 .net Applications. 2 use windows forms, one uses WPF. A couple of weeks ago, some users begun to complain that the 2 win-forms based applications periodicaly hang for several seconds. This can happen on opening menu-items, expanding tree-views, open new windows. During this time, neither network, nor harddisk-operations take place. The CPU's is not busy.

Was there a service pack in the last weeks that may cause .net win-forms applications to react like this? Or has someone another idea or experience? Maybe the antivirus-solution. The AV is MC'Affee, the OS is is windows XP.

The applications were not changed in the last time and they run already for several years without any complaint.

Comment: It would make it easier for us to help you if you tell us version of .Net which the applications use.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: .net 3.5SP1

Comment: Are the programs installed on one computer or several? Are you sure that these problems are specific to your programs and not other ones as well?

Comment: @James: About 50 computers. The computers are IMO not very well installed. I'm not aware of other .net-programms installed that are used frequently. Therefore I can not say if other .net programs have problems. But for the office products, no such behaviour can be observed. Interesting is, that the effect is not always equal strong. There are times, the problem quasi not occurs.It seems to depend on network traffic, but at least for one of theses apps, there is no network operation done - Only at app startup and closing and this is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to engage with the developers. Take a process dump while hanging and pass it to the developers who should be able to determine what the application is doing.

> neither network, nor harddisk-operations take place

Are you sure, brief operations can be very easy to miss. Really need to check with appropriate monitoring software.

> Was there a service pack in the last week

The last update for .NET (I applied here) was security update [MS10-060](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/Bulletin/MS10-060.mspx), released with the August batch (I've seen no issues here), but that was a few weeks ago now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would give you +1 but I can not because I don't have the points necessary. The problem is, that we don't have admin rights on these clients. Therefore profiling is not possible (as far as I know).

Comment: To dump your own process (i.e. same user) you don't need admin permissions.